# Refresh a property's binding after it's parent reference is changed

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, binding

Say I have a ViewModel with a property on it called Customer.  When Customer changes it raises NotifyPropertyChanged.

The Customer class has other properties on it (that all raise NotifyPropertyChanged in the setter).  For example it has Strings of FirstName, and LastName.  Another property in it called Address.

Address has properties like Line1, Line2, Zip, State etc.  They also all raise NotifyPropertyChanged when they are changed.

I have UI elements bound directly to these elements.  I am finding that when I do something like this:

```
CurrentCustomer = FoundCustomer;
```

That the items like FirstName and LastName are getting updated in my BoundControls, but that Line1, Line2, Zip and State are not.

I have experimented with making a ViewModel instance of Address like this:

```
CurrentAddress = FoundCustomer.Address;
```

When I do that, the bound properties update correctly.

Is there something about binding that I am missing?  Does it only update one level deep?  Or only Value (not reference) object?

Or should this be working and I need to look closer at my bindings?

Comment: How is CurrentCustomer bound to the form?

Answer (score 0):

Try instead of raising NotifyPropertyChanged in the setter, try raising the properties somewhere in code only when you need it to be raised.